# Row click event within jquery click function is not working only for last row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a dynamic table as the code shown below. I need clickable rows that take the user to other page.It works fine only till the last but one row.The clickable row functionality is not present in last row.

```
    $(window).load(function(){
       $.get("http://localhost:8080/MusicPlayer/GetSongList", function(data){
          console.log(data);
         var library = data;
         var table = $("#table");
         var row;
         library.songs.forEach(function(song){
             row = $("<tr></tr>");
                $("<td />").addClass("song-select").append($("<input />").attr({type:"checkbox",class:"checkbox",value:song.title})).appendTo(row);
                $("<td>"+song.title+"</td>").appendTo(row);
                $("<td>"+song.album.albumName+"</td>").appendTo(row);
                $("<td>"+song.artist+"</td>").appendTo(row);
                $("<td>"+song.rating+"</td>").appendTo(row);
                $("<td>"+song.composer+"</td>").appendTo(row);
                $("<td>"+song.genre.genreName+"</td>").appendTo(row);
                row.appendTo(table).click(viewFunction());
        });
    });

   }); 
   });

  function viewFunction(){
  $('#table tbody tr td:not(.song-select)').click(function () {
    var songTitle = $(this).parent().children('td:eq(1)').text();
    window.location.assign("http://localhost:8080/MusicPlayer/getSong?songTitle="+songTitle);
   });

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this. You got to use [.on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of the viewFunction.

```
$(function(){
   $.get("http://localhost:8080/MusicPlayer/GetSongList", function(data){
      console.log(data);
     var library = data;
     var table = $("#table body");
     var row;
     library.songs.forEach(function(song){
         row = $("<tr></tr>").data('song-title', song.title);

            $("<td />").addClass("song-select").append($("<input />").attr({type:"checkbox",class:"checkbox",value:song.title})).appendTo(row);
            $("<td>"+song.title+"</td>").appendTo(row);
            $("<td>"+song.album.albumName+"</td>").appendTo(row);
            $("<td>"+song.artist+"</td>").appendTo(row);
            $("<td>"+song.rating+"</td>").appendTo(row);
            $("<td>"+song.composer+"</td>").appendTo(row);
            $("<td>"+song.genre.genreName+"</td>").appendTo(row);
            row.appendTo(table);
    });
});

}); 


$('#table tbody').on('click', 'td:not(.song-select)',function () {
var songTitle = $(this).parent().data('song-title');
location= "http://localhost:8080/MusicPlayer/getSong?songTitle="+songTitle;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.on()` for binding click events for dynamically added row, like below -

```
$('#table tbody').on("click"," tr td:not(.song-select)",function () {
```

But here you are adding `song-select` class to the last row `td`, as shown below

`$("<td />").addClass("song-select").`

and your jquery selector is filtering all `td` which are having `song-select` class, see below

```
$('#table tbody tr td:not(.song-select)').click(function () {
```

Either you need skip adding class to the last row or to change your selector.

Skip adding `class` -

```
$("<td />").append($("<input />").attr({type:"checkbox",class:"checkbox",value:song.title})).appendTo(row);
```

OR

change selector (use `.on()` for binding click event for dynamic row.)

```
$('#table tbody').on('click','tr td',function () {
```

Answer (score -1):

Use event delegation for dynamic elements. Try this:

```
$('#table').on('click','tbody tr td:not(.song-select)'function () {


}
```